# Netsh wlan show profile name=NetworkName key= clear does not show WiFi Password

Tags: wireless-networking, netsh

When I run Netsh wlan show profile name=NetworkName key=clear for some of the wifi networks listed with netshw wlan show profiles from an Admin command prompt the Security section shows Security Key as present but but does not list  the key content. All  Security settings are the same for networks where Key Content is shown as for when Key Content is not shown.

Answer (score 0):

Run the command in admin mode and also add the interface name like below

```
netsh wlan show profiles name="profile 1" interface="interface_name" key=clear
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).